# How to remove all installed dependent packages while removing a package in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, terminal, yum, dependencies, uninstall

I am using CentOS 7. I installed okular, which is a PDF viewer, with the command:

```
sudo yum install okular
```

As you can see in the picture below, it installed 37 dependent packages to install okular.

[image: installed dependencies]

But I wasn't satisfied with the features of the application and I decided to remove it. The problem is that if I remove it with the command:

```
sudo yum autoremove okular
```

It only removes four dependent packages.

[image: removed packages with autoremove]

And if I remove it with the command:

```
sudo yum remove okular
```

It removes only one package which is okular.x86_64.

Now, my question is that is there a way to remove all 37 installed packages with a command or do I have to remove all of them one by one?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Personally, I don't like yum plugins because they don't work a lot of the time, in my experience.

You can use the `yum history` command to view your yum history.

```
[root@testbox ~]# yum history
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager, verify, versionlock
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19 | Jason <jason>  | 2016-06-28 09:16 | Install        |   10
```

You can find info about the transaction by doing `yum history info <transaction id>`. So:

`yum history info 19` would tell you all the packages that were installed with transaction 19 and the command line that was used to install the packages. If you want to undo transaction 19, you would run `yum history undo 19`.

Alternatively, if you just wanted to undo the last transaction you did (you installed a software package and didn't like it), you could just do `yum history undo last`

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your excellent answer. And secondly, when I did `sudo yum history`, it showed only actions with id 30 through 49. Is there a way to view all actions history (including with id 1-29)?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, there is a way to show all of your history. Just do `yum history list all`.

Answer (score 12):

`yum remove package_name` will remove only that package and all their dependencies.

`yum autoremove` will remove the unused dependencies

To remove a package with it's dependencies , you need to install `yum` plugin called: `remove-with-leaves`

To install it type:

```
yum install yum-plugin-remove-with-leaves
```

To remove `package_name` type:

```
yum remove package_name --remove-leaves
```

Comment: I tried your answer, it doesn't work.